# Understanding some code in PHP

Tags: php, ruby

I am a noob programmer who is learning Ruby and I decided to write a SERP checker. The thing is that I'm so noob that I don't know how to go about it so I found a script online that does it, but it's written in PHP. A friend helped me understand the first part of it, where he found a lot of problems with the script. However, as my friend is busy, he cannot help me "decipher" the second part of the script.

I was able to write, in Ruby, up until the $i = 0 and now I'm stuck. I'm trying to figure out what's going on in the rest of the script.
**There are these lines, in particular that baffle me**, I think I can handle the rest, **but have included it all (at the bottom), in the case I am not giving enough information**.

```
            $keyword_implode = str_replace(' ','+',$keywords[$i]);
        $fetch_url = "http://www.google.com/search?num=50&q=" . $keyword_implode . "&btnG=Search";
        ob_start();
        include_once($fetch_url);
        $page = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
```

I looked on php.net for some information on str_replace and none of the examples really resemble (to me) any of the examples, so I'm trying to figure out what he's trying to replace with what.

Here is the whole script:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['url'] != '') {
        if (strpos($_POST['keyword'],"\n")) {
            $keywords = str_replace("\n",",",$_POST['keyword']);
            $keywords = explode(",",$keywords);
        } else {
            $keywords[0] = $_POST['keyword'];
        }
        $keyword_input = $_POST['keyword'];
        $url = $_POST['url'];
    }

    $i = 0;

    if ($keywords[$i] != '') {
        while ($keywords[$i] != '') {
            $keyword_implode = str_replace(' ','+',$keywords[$i]);
            $fetch_url = "http://www.google.com/search?num=50&q=" . $keyword_implode . "&btnG=Search";
            ob_start();
            include_once($fetch_url);
            $page = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();  

            $page = str_replace('<b>','',$page);
            $page = str_replace('</b>','',$page);
            //preg_match('/008000\">(.+)<\/font><nobr>/i', $page, $match);
            preg_match_all('/<font color=#008000>(.*)<\/font>/', $page, $match);
            $r = 0;
            $position = '0';
            while ($match[0][$r] != '') {
                if ($position == '0') {
                    if (strpos($match[0][$r],$url)) {
                        $position = $r+1;
                    } 
                }
                $r++;
            } 
            $google_position = $position;

            $keyword_table .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>' . $keywords[$i] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $google_position . '</td>
                </tr>';
            $i++;
        }
        $keyword_table = '
            <table class="result-table" cellspacing="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Keyword</th>
                    <th>Google</th>
                </tr>' . $keyword_table . '
            </table>';
    }
?>
```

Here's what I've written so far, in Ruby:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rspec'
get '/serp_checker' do
  "<form action='/ranked' method='post'>
  <label for='keyword'>Keyword</label>
  <textarea name='keyword' id='keyword' type='text' /></textarea>
  <label for='url'>URL</label>
  <input name='url' id='url' type='text' />
  <input type='submit' value='Go!' />
  </form>"
end

def clean_up_keywords(str)
  str.gsub("\n", ",").delete("\r").split(',')
end

def clean_up_list(arr)
  arr.reject(&:empty?).each(&:lstrip!)
end

post '/ranked' do
  dirty_list = clean_up_keywords(params[:keyword])
  clean_list = clean_up_list(dirty_list)
  return clean_list.to_s
end
```

Sorry about this being so long, I just wanted to describe the whole problem, so that I don't forget to give out important information about the problem.

Comment: Your PHP script opens a **huge security hole**. If the google output contained PHP tags, it would be executed on your server. Use `$data = file_get_contents($url);` to retrieve remote data instead of `include`!

Comment: With str_replace he's replacing spaces with + signs so the string becomes URL compatible, if that's your only question.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Yeah, this is the script after the guy helping me removed a lot of other things. There were some other crazy things in there. My friend didn't more closely inspect the code as he had things to do. However, I would have never known about the security hole, so thank you for sharing. +1 for telling me about the blip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the section of code you've indicated at the top of your post:

- The first line is replacing any spaces with a + symbol in whatever is inside that part of the array.
- $fetch_url builds a url using the altered string from the first line.
- ob_start activates the output buffer, which prevents anything from being outputted to the page.
- include_once is including the URL built above (if not already included).
- $page = ob_get_contents is assigning the content of the output buffer to the $page variable.
- ob_end_clean wipes the output buffer.

Comment: What is an output buffer? Sorry, newb question. What will happen if I don't use one? What do you mean by "including the url"? The other elements of the code you mention, I'm not sure I understand... because I've never heard of output buffers. :S Great answer, though. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: There's some information on PHP output control here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php. If you don't make use of it then the PHP output will be sent to the browser as it executes (runs through your code). You don't have to use it.